# Remplazar texto de dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

Lo que necesito es reemplazar el texto de un `button`. Quiero reemplazar la palabra `SUCURSAL`.

```
<button id="btnSucursal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>      
    SUCURSAL <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

El problema es que dentro del texto tengo un icono y un `span` que no me gustaría perder.

Hasta el momento, se me reemplaza todo el texto del botón:

```
$('#btnSucursal:contains("SUCURSAL")').text("hola");
```

Necesito reemplazar el texto, sin perder:

```
<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

ni

```
<span  class="caret"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un span en el texto:

```
<button id="btnSucursal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle"
                              data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>      
                        <span id="btnText">SUCURSAL</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
```

De ahi puedes cambiarlo directamente:

```
$("#btnText").text("nuevoTexto");
```

Answer (score 0):

La función **`.text()`** o **`.html()`** the **jQuery** reemplaza todo lo que se encuentre dentro del padre (en este caso el botón), por lo tanto te está **reemplazando todo por "hola"**, para hacer lo que pretendes te recomiendo que agregues otro **span** a tu botón que tenga una clase en específico como por ejemplo `.button_text` y después **buscas dentro de este botón el span que contenga esa clase**, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$('#btnSucursal').find(".button_text").html("hola");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnSucursal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">=></i>
    <span class="button_text"></span>
  <span class="caret">||</span>
</button>
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Esto es una solucion funcional

```
<button id="btnSucursal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle"
                              data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>      
                        <a  style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;' id="texto">SUCURSAL<a> <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
```

el java script seria el siguiente

```
$(document).on("ready", function(e){
    $("#btnSucursal").on("click", function(e){
        $("#btnSucursal >a#texto").text("Cambio");
    });
});
```